# Python, websocket auto-close on some machines

Tags: python, websocket

I've written some api to communicate with a website using websocketapp. It works fine only on 2 pc. If i put my code on every other pc the websocket doesnt receive any message and closes. I've tried a lot of different machines and operating systems, many version of python (included the same that works), wireless and wired connection but nothing changed. There's no error or exception. What can it be?

EDIT: i don't own the website or the server. All other methods send messages and parse the response in on_socket_message

```
import requests
import websocket
import time
from threading import Thread
from  datetime import datetime
import json
from position import Position
from constants import ACTIVES


class IQOption():

    practice_balance = 0
    real_balance = 0
    server_time = 0
    positions = {}
    instruments_categories = ["cfd","forex","crypto"]
    top_assets_categories = ["forex","crypto","fx-option"]
    instruments_to_id = ACTIVES
    id_to_instruments = {y:x for x,y in ACTIVES.items()}
    market_data = {}
    binary_expiration_list = {}
    open_markets = {}
    digital_strike_list = {}
    candle_data = []
    latest_candle = 0
    position_id = 0
    quotes =[]
    position_id_list=[]


    def __init__(self,username,password,host="iqoption.com"):

        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.host = host
        self.session = requests.Session()
        self.generate_urls()
        self.socket = websocket.WebSocketApp(self.socket_url,on_open=self.on_socket_connect,on_message=self.on_socket_message,on_close=self.on_socket_close,on_error=self.on_socket_error)

    def generate_urls(self):
        """Generates Required Urls to operate the API"""
        #https://auth.iqoption.com/api/v1.0/login
        self.api_url = "https://{}/api/".format(self.host)
        self.socket_url = "wss://{}/echo/websocket".format(self.host)
        self.login_url = self.api_url+"v1.0/login"
        self.profile_url = self.api_url+"profile"
        self.change_account_url = self.profile_url+"/"+"changebalance"
        self.getprofile_url = self.api_url+"getprofile"

    def login(self):
        """Login and set Session Cookies"""
        print("LOGIN")
        data = {"email":self.username,"password":self.password}
        self.log_resp = self.session.request(url="https://auth.iqoption.com/api/v1.0/login",data=data,method="POST")
        requests.utils.add_dict_to_cookiejar(self.session.cookies, dict(platform="9"))
        self.__ssid = self.log_resp.cookies.get("ssid")
        print(self.__ssid)
        self.start_socket_connection()
        time.sleep(1) ## artificial delay to complete socket connection
        self.log_resp2 = self.session.request(url="https://eu.iqoption.com/api/getprofile",method="GET")
        ss = self.log_resp2._content.decode('utf-8')
        js_ss=json.loads(ss)
        self.parse_account_info(js_ss)
        self.balance_id = js_ss["result"]["balance_id"]
        self.get_instruments()
        self.get_top_assets()
        self.setOptions()
        #self.getFeatures()
        time.sleep(1)
        print(js_ss["isSuccessful"])
        return js_ss["isSuccessful"]

    def on_socket_message(self,socket,message):
        #do things

    def on_socket_connect(self,socket):
        """Called on Socket Connection"""
        self.initial_subscriptions()
        print("On connect")

    def initial_subscriptions(self):
        self.send_socket_message("ssid",self.__ssid)
        self.send_socket_message("subscribe","tradersPulse")

    def on_socket_error(self,socket,error):
        """Called on Socket Error"""
        print(message)   

    def on_socket_close(self,socket):
        """Called on Socket Close, does nothing"""

    def start_socket_connection(self):
        """Start Socket Connection"""
        self.socket_thread = Thread(target=self.socket.run_forever)
        self.socket_thread.start()

    def send_socket_message(self,name,msg):
        #print(msg)
        data = {"name":name,"msg":msg}
        self.socket.send(json.dumps(data))
```

Comment: You need to post code.  I use websockets and don't have a problem, so if you post code I can help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example running under Gevent Websockets.  This makes it ASYNC (which I suspect is part of your problem) and allows for bidirectional communication.

```
import gevent
from gevent import monkey, signal, Timeout, sleep, spawn as gspawn
monkey.patch_all()
from gevent.pywsgi import WSGIServer
from geventwebsocket.handler import WebSocketHandler
from geventwebsocket import WebSocketError
import bottle
from bottle import get, route, template, request, response, abort, static_file
import ujson as json

@route('/static/<filepath:path>')
def server_static(filepath):
    return static_file(filepath, root='static')

@route('/ws/remote')
def handle_websocket():
    wsock = request.environ.get('wsgi.websocket')
    if not wsock:
        abort(400, 'Expected WebSocket request.')
    while 1:
        try:
            message = ''            
            with Timeout(2, False) as timeout:
                message = wsock.receive()
            if message:
                message = json.loads(message)
                if 'command' in message:
                    r.command(message['command'])
        except WebSocketError:
            break
        except Exception as exc:
            print(str(exc))


@get('/')
def remote():
    return template('templates/remote.tpl', title='WebsocketTest', websocket=WEBSOCKET, command='command', status=status)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    r=None
    status="Connecting..."
    gspawn(initialize)
    print 'Started...'
    HOST = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
    HOST = 'localhost'
    WEBSOCKET =  'ws://{}/ws/remote'.format(HOST)
    botapp = bottle.app()
    server = WSGIServer(("0.0.0.0", 80), botapp, handler_class=WebSocketHandler)
    def shutdown():
        print('Shutting down ...')
        server.stop(timeout=60)
        exit(signal.SIGTERM)
    gevent.signal(signal.SIGTERM, shutdown)
    gevent.signal(signal.SIGINT, shutdown) #CTRL C
    server.serve_forever()
```

Then in your HTML you really should use reconnecting websocket library
https://github.com/joewalnes/reconnecting-websocket

```
<button id="TRIGGERED" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary">TRIGGER</button>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/reconnecting-websocket.min.js"></script>
<script>
var ws = new ReconnectingWebSocket('{{websocket}}');
ws.reconnectInterval = 3000;
ws.maxReconnectAttempts = 10;

ws.onmessage = function (evt) {
    var wsmsg = JSON.parse(evt.data);
    console.log(evt.data)
    };


$("button").click(function() {
    <!--console.log(this.id);-->
    ws.send(JSON.stringify({'{{command}}': this.id}));
});
</script>
```